# Remove characters from output in each row

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010, exchange-management-shell

I am a newbie to PowerShell and I am struggling to modify an output according to the way I want.

The command I run in MS Exchange Shell is this:

```
Get-Mailbox user1 | Get-ADPermission | ? {($_.ExtendedRights -like "*send-as*") -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} | Select User
```

The result I get from the above command is:

```
User              
----              
AGL\user4
AGL\user5
AGL\groupX
```

However I would like to obtain the output as:

```
User              
----              
user4
user5
groupX
```

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks heaps in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, use a [Calculated Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) to output the objects with their names only:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity user1 | 
    Get-ADPermission | 
    Where-Object {($_.ExtendedRights -like "*send-as*") -and ($_.User -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'User'; Expression = {$_.User.Split("\",2)[1]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little testing,  You can try

```
(Get-Mailbox user1 | Get-ADPermission | ? {($_.ExtendedRights -like "*send-as*") -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} | Select User).TrimStart("AGL\")
```

If that doesn't work you can try

```
$Rights = Get-Mailbox user1 | Get-ADPermission | ? {($_.ExtendedRights -like "*send-as*") -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} | Select User

$Rights = $Rights.TrimStart("AGL\")
```

The trim will trim the start up to the point of the back slash, as long as the string stays the same.